# Set the value of a textField in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got an `NSTextField` called `resultsView` that I'd like to populate with the string `graphical_availability`.

I've tried the following:

```
[resultsView setValue:graphical_availability];
```

but keep getting an error during runtime:

```
2012-08-13 08:39:08.468 App-Name[75231:6003] -[NSTextField setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100509730
2012-08-13 08:39:08.470 App-Name[75231:6003] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-08-13 08:39:08.470 App-Name[75231:6003] -[NSTextField setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100509730
```

So, obviously `setValue` isn't recognized as a method on the `NSTextField` class that I'm using. I'm new to Objective-C (obviously) and have had trouble finding it on Apple's docs.

How can I set the value of this textField?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setStringValue:` is the method you need.

From the [NSTextField class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Overview**
>
> The parent class, NSControl, provides the methods for setting the values of the text field, for example: setStringValue:, setDoubleValue:, etc.. There are corresponding methods to retrieve values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the underscore to call the setter:

```
[_resultsView setStringValue:graphical_availability];
```